# How hydrocele can appear after varicocelectomy? What is hydrocele?

Tags: urology

The patient has Microscopic subinguinal varicocelectomy (or Marmar operation), which resulted in hydrocele

During Marmar operation the veins vere dissected (probably with lymphatic cords)

How this resulted to hydrocele? If I understand correctly the fluid comes from abdomen because processus vaginalis is reopened again, but how and why it reopened? Is it linked to damaged lymphatic cords?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your guess seems to be correct. Iatrogenic lymphatic leakage should be the reason for hydrocele after Marmar operation.

[The role of microsurgical varicocelectomy in treating male infertility](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5583050/):

> Hydrocele following varicocelectomy is the result of inadvertent ligation of efferent lymphatics